# Material UI doesn't render anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I tried adding a navbar to my website but react does not render a thing.
I tried making a new project and that did not work either.
Also stackoverflow prevents posts that are mostly code I do not know why this is a thing.

My App.js

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container"


function App() {
  return (
     <Container>
         <Navbar></Navbar>
     </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';


import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';

let darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        mode: 'dark',
    },
});


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
            <CssBaseline/>
            <App></App>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>

);
```

I'm using

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
"@mui/material": "^5.10.5",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded react and react-dom to version 17.0.2. This solved the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).